# Calculate the length of a string in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following hexadecimal string

```
VAR='\x45\x8A\xC8\x4E\x58\xBB\x16\x17\x55\x96\xA5\x26\xD1\xDA\x56\x04\xA7\xBD\x6F\xA5'
```

I need to find the number of bytes of it which is 20.
But if I type

```
length=${#VAR}
echo "var length: "$length
```

I get 80. How can I do? 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Since you have indicated that you are happy with chepner's answer, see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't have 20 bytes; it has 80, since `\x45` is 4 individual characters, not a literal representing a single byte. `VAR=$'\x45...'` would give you the 20-byte string you expect.

Comment: So if given a literal string `foo='\x45\x8A\xC8\x4E\x58\xBB\x16\x17\x55\x96\xA5\x26\xD1\xDA\x56\x04\xA7\xBD\x6F\xA5'` how do I transform it and get 20?

Comment: @dibery `var='\x45\x8A\xC8\x4E\x58\xBB\x16\x17\x55\x96\xA5\x26\xD1\xDA\x56\x04\xA7\xBD\x6F\xA5'; echo "${#var}"` → output:
`80` then `var=$'\x45\x8A\xC8\x4E\x58\xBB\x16\x17\x55\x96\xA5\x26\xD1\xDA\x56\x04\xA7\xBD\x6F\xA5'; echo "${#var}"` → output: 
`20`

Comment: Uh no, suppose I'm not allowed to add `$` in front of the string (variable content set elsewhere like `foo=$(magic_cmd)`), how do I continue?

Comment: Why would someone provide a string like this as input to a shell script? Either the input should change, or you should use a different language.

Comment: @dibery - bit of a kludge: `var2=$(echo -e ${var}); echo ${#var2}` => 20

Comment: what if I have the hexadecimal string stored in a file and I need to convert it into its 20 byte string?
I tried to read it with  `value=$(<file.bin) `  but what shall I do next?

Comment: Fix your file. Whoever created it was under the mistaken impression that this is a good way to store binary data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wc`

```
echo $VAR | wc -c

$ wc --help
Usage: wc [OPTION]... [FILE]...
  or:  wc [OPTION]... --files0-from=F
...
The options below may be used to select which counts are printed, always in
the following order: newline, word, character, byte, maximum line length.
  -c, --bytes            print the byte counts
```